# Superman comic story where he wears a different costume and has an actor pretend to be him

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, superman

I vaguely remember this Superman story. It involves Superman being in disguise in a different costume with a helmet I think... while an actor pretending to be Superman wears a ring that allows him to fly. I think this was some kind of scheme Superman and the actor cooked up to mislead a villain.

Other vague details I remember... they were filming a Superman television show... the dialogue said that Superman's thoughts were at a certain speed. Superman corrected the director by saying his thoughts were much faster than that. The director said that was far too unrealistic for audiences.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you’re remembering [Superman 396](http://Superman%20Vol%201%20396) from 1984.

[image: cover: “Superman: The battle is on! And the prize is—Superman!”]

In the story Superman visits a film crew shooting the latest Superman movie. Superman mentions that the actor’s line about how quickly he came up with the solution to the problem in the movie was inaccurate and that his brain is much faster than that. This got the attention of a villain called Intellex the Brain Bandit that specializes in stealing advanced brains to use as biological computers. The villain attacks but Superman recovers and the villain gets away.

[image: panel where Intellex introduces himself]

The next day Intellex tries again by attacking Superman with enlarged viruses. This time Superman is helped by a new hero called the Mystery Masquerader who easily gets rid of the viruses. Further attempts by the villain are thwarted by appearances by the Mystery Masquerader until Intellex get the idea to let the heroes fight each other. By using a hypnotizing ray on the Mystery Masquerader he gets him in his power and he defeats Superman.

[image: MM: “call me again if you need me”. SM: “I hope it doesn’t come to that!”]

Intellex teleports them all to his base where the Mystery Masquerader fakes helping Intellex to prepare Superman’s brain, instead he destroys Intellex machinery. Intellex demands to know who the Mystery Masquerader is and it is revealed that he is Superman in disguise. The Superman they fought was the actor from the Superman movie, Gregory Reed. The ray had no effect on kryptonians and Superman had staged the whole thing to get Intellex to reveal his hideout.

[image: Gregory Reed explains what Supermans plan was]

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you very much!

Comment: This story came out in 1984, well after the release of the real 'Superman' movie, but Gregory Reed had been appearing in the comics since before that. His name was, of course, a reference to George Reeves, who starred in the 1950s television series.

Comment: The silver age was wild.

Comment: This is bronze age,silver age was even wilder! It introduced Gregory Reed as a villainous lookalike actor that had his real face destroyed in an accident and that tried to get his looks back by swapping bodies with Superman through black magic. This story nearly makes sense in comparison.